# How do I list block devices in Go?

Tags: linux, go

I want to get the data shown by `lsblk` command in Linux 64-bit systems. Obviously I can call `lsblk` and parse the output. My question is if there is a better way to do this in Go?

Thanks.

Comment: The `lsblk` man page says that "The lsblk command reads the sysfs filesystem and udev db to gather information."  Since `lsblk` is already available and already does what you want, knowing where to gather information from the system and how to synthesize that information, I'd think using it would be the best way.  Unless there's some non-obvious definition of "better" for your particular use case.

Comment: Parsing output of a command feels hacky. So, I was wondering if there is any kind of syscall or etc to call to get this data.

Comment: I know what you mean.  The `lsblk` source code is here: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/lsblk.c

At first glance, personally, it seems nontrivial to replicate that in Go, and probably worth the hassle of parsing output and testing for breakage when the `util-linux` package is updated.  But it's definitely a decision that has to be made for your individual project based on your particular criteria.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the source. I will probably parse the output :(

Answer (score 1):

Since `lsblk` is already available and already does what you want (gathering information from the system and synthesizing that information into the form you want), I'd think using it would be the best way.

The `lsblk` source code is here: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/lsblk.c.  At first glance, personally, this seems nontrivial to replicate in Go, and probably worth the hassle of parsing output and testing for breakage when the util-linux package is updated.

That's ultimately a decision that has to be made for your individual project based on your particular criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed the names of the top-level devices and ended up simply listing the contents of `/sys/block`, which was convenient because it requires neither running a command, nor parsing output.

```golang
func GetDevices() []string {
    dir, err := ioutil.ReadDir("/sys/block")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    files := make([]string, 0)

    for _, f := range dir {
        if strings.HasPrefix(f.Name(), "loop") {
            continue
        }
        files = append(files, f.Name())
    }

    return files
}
```

Neither a very robust or portable solution, but worked for what I needed.

You could also conceive parsing the contents of `/proc/diskstats` or `/proc/partitions`.